# than is thought by

Tags: comparative-constructions

> New research involving tiger salamanders indicates that the
>   traditional theory of natural selection is more strongly supported by
>   the evidence than is **thought by** those who consider only the case
>   of the spadefoot toad tadpole.

What does **thought by** means in this sentence? Is it compared with **supported by** (supported by ... than thought by...)?

Answer (score 1):

*Is thought* is a passive; convert this to active voice, with the object of *by* as the subject:

> Those who consider only the case of the spadefoot toad tadpole do not **think** that the traditional theory of natural selection is strongly supported.
>
> But new research involving tiger salamanders suggest that the theory is  supported more strongly than those scientists **think**.

*Think* in this context means *believe*.